# Downloading Photos to iPad and adding them to iCloud photos

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos

I'm in a bit of pickle I'm home at my parents and they have an old windows laptop (very old basically no way to install any software on it) from which we copied photos on to an USB stick and then uploaded them via my laptop (linux) to wetransfer to download them to an iPad. I downloaded them with Safari to the iPad and now they are unzipped and and are syncing with the iCloud drive. How do I get them to show up in the photos app and add them to iCloud photos?